# Stream.of with mixed input contents

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'm wondering if it would be possible to replace the following piece of code:

```
Object o;

// o can be one of the two following things
o = Arrays.asList("Toto", "tata", "Titi");
o = "Test";

if (o instanceof List<?>) {
    ((List<?>) o).stream().forEach(System.out::println);
} else {
    System.out.println(o);
}
```

By something less ugly using `Stream.of`. I thought of this:

```
Object o;

// o can be one of the two following things
o = Arrays.asList("Toto", "tata", "Titi");
o = "Test";

Stream.of(o).forEach(System.out::println);
```

But obviously it does not work as `Stream.of(aList)` does not "flatten" its contents.

Any ideas? Am I dreaming of something that does not exist?

Thanks

PS. I do not know the `Object` type before the `forEach` call. The pieces of code are just an easy example of the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want something “less ugly”, you should not widen you data types to `Object` in the first place:

```
List<String> o;

// o can be one of the two following things
o = Arrays.asList("Toto", "tata", "Titi");
o = Collections.singletonList("Test");

o.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Of course, if you have an `Object`, you can do something like

```
(o instanceof List? ((List<?>)o).stream(): Stream.of(o)).forEach(System.out::println);
```

but I’d consider this still as ugly as your original approach…

Comment: Well actually this partially solves the problem. My main concern is that **I do not know** the object type before the call, it can be either a list or a single object and I wish to stream it afterwards. As I don't know the object type I can't do `Collections.singletonList` on an already existing list...

Answer (score 1):

What about this (it does not make it more readable of what you already have in place IMO)

```
 Stream.of(o).flatMap(
                  x -> x instanceof List<?> ? ((List<?>) x).stream() : Stream.of(x))
              .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Lots of calls for not that much benefit :/

Comment: @Jerome well yes.. If we knew you can change `o` to be a `List`, things would have been much simpler, but then you already got an answer.

Comment: I know, I've edited my post and actually I do not know before the call if `o` is a list or a single object

Comment: @Jerome well in this case, there *is no way* to check type without `instanceOf`. Either this check goes into an `if`, a `Stream`, etc, ultimately it will do the same checking. At this point I find it just a style problem.

Comment: You're right this is why in the first place I asked if this was just a dream.... `Stream.of(aList)` could return `list.stream()` and this would solve the problem...

Answer (score 1):

The best option would be to refactor the code so you don't work with an `Object`, but with *either* a `List` or whatever the other type is.

If that is not possible, do you really need to stream through the list? Would a simple `System.out.println()` on the list do? That would give the below output:

> [Toto, tata, Titi]

If you truly need to print the content on separate lines, **you can't avoid downcasting the `Object` to a `List`**, since you need to call the `stream()` method on it. The only thing I really can come up with here is to put the casting in a method that isolates that code:

```
private <T> Stream<T> toStream(T object) {
  return object instanceof List ? ((List) object).stream() : Stream.of(object);
}
```

Then just call the method with `o`:

```
toStream(o).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: I can't avoid working with Object(s) as the real code is far more complicated and quite generic. Your solution works for sure but I'd consider it close to as ugly as the base one.

Comment: @Jerome Agreed, but as I also say in my answer, it is the code that forces the cast that should be refactored. Not much else to do other than down cast the object.

Answer (score 0):

Looks quite ugly, but what about something like this?

```
Stream stream = 
        Optional.of(o).
                filter(x -> x instanceof List).
                map(x -> ((List) x).stream()).
                orElse(Stream.of(o));
stream.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: This is probably just a matter of personal preference, but I find it easier to read the old-style `Stream stream = (o instanceOf List<?> ? ((List<?>) o).stream() : Stream.of(o);` instead of a series of method calls on `Optional`.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou, I agree. It would be nice if java supports scala like partitioning `List(- 2, - 4,5,7,1) partition  (x => x > 0)` which returns list of negative and list of positive integers.